# XSL: Generate a global integer id that increments itself

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML format that I need to generate via XSL that has an odd quirk. Every element in the target schema that has an id attribute, must be in sequence with all other id attributes, regardless of the element name. Here is a very simplified example of what I mean:

Input.XML

```
<list>
  <booklist>
    <book>
  </booklist>
  <cdlist>
    <cd />
    <cd />
  </cdlist>
  <periodicallist>
    <periodical>
  </periodicallist>
</list>
```

Output.XML

```
<mediaLibrary>
  <book id="1" />
  <cdList>
    <cd id="2" />
    <cd id="3" />
  </cdList>
  <periodical id="4" />
</mediaLibrary>
```

I know that XSL variables are immutable and I haven't had any luck with xsl:number, though I am very new to XSL. Is there a way in XSL to do this?

Comment: Why don't you post the XSLT that produces the above output (without the ids)?  -- BTW, is it really necessary for the ids to be consecutive integers? Wouldn't *unique* ids be sufficient?

Comment: The id's don't have to appear in order, but if there are 4 id attributes then there needs to be the numbers 1,2,3,4 (or 4,2,1,3 etc...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I haven't had any luck with xsl:number

How about:

```
<xsl:number level="any" count="book | cd | periodical"/>
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize that you could use | on items in the count attribute